# Exit Code 1 on device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, launch, xcode10.1

Ive made a WebView App for my website. In Xcode the app in launching very well. When I try to launch it on my iPhone Xcode give me an Error Code 1.
With the iPhone XS Max Simulator it works very well. When I try to launch the app on my own iPhone I get this error:

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app (in target: Street Grinders)
    cd /Users/josh/Dropbox/Privat/Informatik/xCode/Street\ Grinders
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 400C67DB1377BA23C17CA6E2B85028CD6D274F37 --scan-executable /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app/Street\ Grinders --scan-folder /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Street\ Grinders.build/Debug-iphoneos/Street\ Grinders.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep



Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
libswiftos.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code object is not signed at all



Codesigning /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 400C67DB1377BA23C17CA6E2B85028CD6D274F37 --verbose /Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/josh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Street_Grinders-dyxbiwhbhtsqtlgfqwomvorkwyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Street Grinders.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: errSecInternalComponent
```

> error: Failed with exit code 1

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your derived data?

Comment: Just cleaning the project might also work.

Comment: my certificate was wrong.. problem solved!